# Vuex accessing namespaced module getters in vue router

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router, vuex

I am trying to guard my routes by checking if the user is authenticated, this is the example route:

```
{
  path: '/intranet',
  component: search,
  meta: { requiresAuth: true },
  props: {
    tax: 'type',
    term: 'intranet-post',
    name: 'Intranet'
  }
},
```

And I am setting the guard like this:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {

    let authenticated = this.$store.getters['auth/getAuthenticated'];

    if (!authenticated) {
      next({
        path: '/login',
        query: { redirect: to.fullPath }
      })
    } else {
      next()
    }
  } else {
    next()
  }
})
```

This is the vuex module for auth:

```
import Vue from "vue";

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    authenticated: !!localStorage.getItem("token"),
    token: localStorage.getItem("token")
  },
  mutations: {
    login: function(state, token){
        state.authenticated = true;
        state.token = token;
    },
    logout: function(state){
        state.authenticated = false;
        state.token = '';
    }
  },
  actions: {
    login: function({commit}, token){
      localStorage.setItem('token', token);
      commit('login', token);
    },
    logout: function({commit}){
      localStorage.removeItem("token");
      commit('logout');
    }
  },
  getters: {
    getToken: (state) => state.token,
    getAuthenticated: (state) => state.authenticated,
  }
}
```

But, when I try to access the auth getter like it is shown in the route guard, I get an error:

> Cannot read property 'getters' of undefined

What am I doing wrong, how can I fix this?

Comment: can you post the complete code from the file where you use `router.beforeEach` ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The error message states that `this.$store` is undefined when it tries to access `this.$store.getters`, so the problem seems that the store is not initialized or set up the way you expect it to within the router. Accessing the namespaced getters using `.getters['name/getter']` is in itself correct.

Following some tutorials, I have `store.js` which defines my store, and then I import it in my `router.js` like this:

```
import store from './store'
```

and then access it directly with `store` instead of `this.$store`:

```
let authenticated = store.getters['auth/getAuthenticated'];
```

I think the problem is that `this.$store` is automatically added to Vue-Components, but the router is not really a component, and is thus missing the `$store`-member. Importing the store works around this.