# "state.user is null" when using Vue'x getter in my routes

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I'm used to VueJS but I have next to no knowledge with Vuex.

Basically, I want to setup a role-based router system: the JSON my API returns is an object that contains an array with the user's roles, stringified so that I can parse it from Vue.

I followed some tutorials, and after some tweaks, here is how my store looks (relevant part):

```
getters: {
    isLogged: state => !!state.user,

    roles: state => JSON.parse(state.user.user.roles) // returns ['authenticated_user', 'admin']
}
```

If I test the 'roles' getter with a `mapGetter` inside a component, I won't have any trouble getting my datas. However, I keep getting `state.user is null` displayed as an error in my console.

Here is how I tried to set it up:

```
const routes = [
    ...
    {
        path: '/admin',
        name: 'admin',
        component: () => import('../admin/Dashboard'),
        meta: {
            auth: true,
            role: 'admin'
       }
    },
    ...

];

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    const loggedIn = localStorage.getItem('user');
    const role = store.getters.roles;
    console.log(store.getters.roles); // state.user is null

    if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.auth) && !loggedIn) {
        next('/login');
        return;
    }

    if (loggedIn && to.match.some(record => !roles.includes(record.meta.role)) {
        next(from.fullPath);
        return;
    }

    next();
});
```

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46908306/vuex-accessing-namespaced-module-getters-in-vue-router) that's the closest from my situation but it didn't help me, since Vue seems to acknowledge `state.user` in my case.

What am I missing?

Thank you in advance

Comment: what about if you log `console.log(store.getters)`?

Comment: It looks like `state.user` is null-able based on `isLogged`. It's likely `state.user` is still uninitialized/unset when `router.beforeEach` is invoked. You should probably add a null-check in that getter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alter roles getter to this: 
`roles: state => state.user && JSON.parse(state.user.user.roles)`

First check if state.user exists and then try get value.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realized that this was asynchronous, I should have thought about that!